# Unmark previously marked annotation while marking related one

Tags: uima, ruta

Here is my input:

```
person
the private person
```

Here are my rules

```
DECLARE Person;
DECLARE PrivatePerson;

ANY{REGEXP("person") -> MARK(Person)};

ANY{AFTER(Person), REGEXP("private") -> MARK(PrivatePerson), UNMARK(Person)};
```

How can I make `Person` in "private person" unmarked (but leave `PrivatePerson` marked)?

`UNMARK(Person)` does not work

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the following suits you but it'll work:

```
W{REGEXP("private")} Person {->UNMARK(Person),MARK(PrivatePerson,1,2)};
```

I put 1,2 so that the annotation span contains *private* too.

On your conditions, you need to have **BEFORE** not **AFTER**. That will create an annotation **PrivatePerson**. However, the unmarking won't happen because of the fact that the rules only apply to what is matched. What is matched in your rule is the string "private" and nothing else. The **BEFORE(Person)** is just a condition, so the rule UNMARK(Person) in the specific occasion does nothing.

Also, prefer **Document** instead of **ANY**, because **ANY** goes to every token (for me it is both RutaBasic and SW) and creates duplicate annotations, whereas with **Document** I end up with one instance of each. I'm not sure though if you experience the same behavior.